# App Crashes when touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

when i build the app i get a warning on the UITouch line saying

> Incompatible Object-c initializing 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct UITouch *'

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] allObjects];
        player.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    }
```

and when i run the app it all starts fine until i click the player and then it closes down. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you meant:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

or:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

`-allObjects` method returns `NSArray` of your touches, if you want to get single object from set you need to use `-anyObject` method:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `myTouch` is a pointer to a `UITouch` object. However, if you look at the documentation, you will find that `allTouches` of a `UIEvent` returns an `NSSet`, and `allObjects` of an `NSSet` returns an `NSArray`. You are therefore trying to tell the computer that `myTouch` is going to get a `UITouch` object passed in, when it will almost certainly get an `NSArray`.

Like putting a square peg in a round hole.